# binding data to attribute by iterating

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following ForEach in my razor where i am setting some values.
It works fine. I can see my all values.

```
 @foreach (var item in Model.ConsultantDetails.ScopeOfSevrices)
     {
      <div id="optionValue" class="item" data-value=>@item.Name</div>
    }
```

Then i have an ajax call and get the result back.
I want to set this data back to same DIV by iterating

```
 $.each(data.ConsultantDetails.ScopeOfSevrices, function (index) {
   $('optionValue').attr("data-value=>", data.ConsultantDetails.ScopeOfSevrices[index].Name);
  });
```

No luck, how do i achieve that?

Comment: It should be `=` not `=>` and use `.attr(key, value)` i.e. `.attr("data-value", data.ConsultantDetails.ScopeOfSevrices[index].Name)`

Comment: If you look at your foreach it will, if you have more than 1 item, duplicate the id `optionValue`, you should not have duplicated id's

Comment: @Satpal no luck it still does not update binding. I see old value

Answer (score 0):

1. use for loop instead of foreach, so we can set seprate id to each iteration
2. dont use data-value=> ,  instead use data-value=" " or some dummy value (here we use : item.Name)

   ```
   @for (int i = 0; i < Model.ProductTypeService.Count; i++)
     {
      var item = Model.ProductTypeService[i];
      var id = "optionValue" + i;
      <div id="@id" class="item" data-value="@item.Name">@item.Name</div>
     }
   ```
3. finally, in jquery, we can assign attribute value based on div id

   ```
    $.each(data.ProductTypeService, function (index) {
               $('#optionValue' + index).attr("data-value", data.ProductTypeService[index].Name + index);  //  + index // just to see different value
           });
   ```