# Create new div attribute with value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following jQuery code that creates new Div and append it to parent with some attributes.

```
 $.each(data.ConsultantDetails.ScopeOfSevrices, function (index) {
   $("#parentOptionDiv").append($('<div/>', {
     "id": data.ConsultantDetails.ScopeOfSevrices[index].Value,
     "class": 'item',
     "data-value":''
   }))
 });
```

It renders HTML

```
<div id="9" class="item" data-value=""></div>
```

How to put value in between `<div> My Value </div>`

Expected

```
<div id="9" class="item" data-value="">MY Value</div>
```

Comment: looks like your old question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47429021/binding-data-to-attribute-by-iterating

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `text` option:

```
$.each(data.ConsultantDetails.ScopeOfSevrices, function (index) {
  $("#parentOptionDiv").append($('<div/>', {
    "id": data.ConsultantDetails.ScopeOfSevrices[index].Value,
    "class": 'item',
    "data-value":'',
    "text": "My Value"
  }))
});
```

This is covered by [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery-html-attributes) for that form of `$()` call:

> As of jQuery 1.4, any event type can be passed in, and the following jQuery methods can be called: `val`, `css`, `html`, `text`, `data`, `width`, `height`, or `offset`.

Answer (score 3):

Use `text` like this

```js
$("#parentOptionDiv").append($('<div/>', {
  "class": 'item',
  "data-value": '',
  "text": "My value"
}))
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="parentOptionDiv"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how to do it with plain JavaScript ( works with JQuery! )

```
var div = document.createElement("div"); // Create new element or use existing element
div.innerText = "The text";              // Set the text
// or ..
var text = document.createTextNode("The text"); // Create a text node
div.appendChild(text);                          // Append text node to div
// Or if you want to append another element
var anotherElement = document.createElement("div"); // Create new element or use existing element
div.appendChild(anotherElement);                    // Append the other element into the div
```